# How does POSIX Threads work in linux?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I thought pthread uses *clone* to spawn one new *thread* in linux. But if so, all of the threads should have their seperate *pid*. Otherwise, if they have the same *pid*, the global variables in the *libc* seem to be shared. However, as I ran the following program, I got the same *pid* but the different address of *errno*.

```
extern errno;
void*
f(void *arg)
{
    printf("%u,%p\n", getpid(), &errno);
    fflush(stdin);
    return NULL;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, f, NULL);
    printf("%u,%p\n", getpid(), &errno);
    fflush(stdin);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Then, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how clone() is used when pthread_create() is called. That said, looking at the [clone() man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone), it looks like there is a flag called `CLONE_THREAD` which:

> If CLONE_THREAD is set, the child is
>   placed in the same thread group as the
>   calling process. To make the remainder
>   of the discussion of CLONE_THREAD more
>   readable, the term "thread" is used to
>   refer to the processes within a thread
>   group.
>
> Thread groups were a feature added in
>   Linux 2.4 to support the POSIX threads
>   notion of a set of threads that share
>   a single PID. Internally, this shared
>   PID is the so-called thread group
>   identifier (TGID) for the thread
>   group. Since Linux 2.4, calls to
>   getpid(2) return the TGID of the
>   caller.

It then goes on to talk about a [gettid()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettid) function for getting the unique ID of an individual thread within a process. Modifying your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int errno;
void*
f(void *arg)
{
    printf("%u,%p, %u\n", getpid(), &errno, syscall(SYS_gettid));
    fflush(stdin);
    return NULL;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, f, NULL);
    printf("%u,%p, %u\n", getpid(), &errno, syscall(SYS_gettid));
    fflush(stdin);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

(make sure to use "-lpthread"!) we can see that the individual thread id is indeed unique, while the pid remains the same.

```
rascher@coltrane:~$ ./a.out 
4109,0x804a034, 4109
4109,0x804a034, 4110
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! But what about the errno that is *extern*ed from the glibc? It is unique, too.(While a regular global variable is shared)

Comment: This is correct - the kernel space "PID" is the user space "TID", and the the kernel space "TGID" is the user space "PID".

Comment: @dutor: `errno` isn't a simple `extern` variable - it has special handling to make it per-thread (it is defined with a macro: `#define errno (*__errno_location ())`

Answer (score 3):

1. Global variables: your mistake is that `errno` is not a global variable but a macro that expands to an lvalue of type `int`. In practice, it expands to `(*__errno_location())` or similar.
2. `getpid` is a library function that returns the *process* id in the POSIX sense of process, not the bogus Linux per-`clone` pid. Nowadays Linux has the minimal kernel-level functionality necessary to make near-POSIX-compliance possible with respect to threads, but most of it still depends on ugly hacks at the userspace libc level.